# Symfony/vue - how to passe data from controller to vue

Tags: symfony, vue.js, webpack

I'm using Symfony 5 / twig with webpack.encore and vue.js.

I passing datas (translation texts) to the used twig-template like this:

Controller:

```
class HomepageController extends AbstractController
{
    const PAGE_ID = 2; // constants PageId

    /**
    * @Route("{_locale}/homepage", name="app_homepage")
    *
    */
    public function index(Request $request,SpracheRepository $spracheRepository)
    {
        $arrTrans = $spracheRepository->findAllOfSpecificPage(self::PAGE_ID,$request->getLocale());

        return $this->render('core/homepage/homepage.html.twig', [
            'headline' => $arrTrans['lb_overview'],
            'pageId' => self::PAGE_ID,
            'arrTrans' => $arrTrans
        ]);
    }
}
```

...and I'd like to access the datas "arrTrans" in the vue file.

The html.twig is looking like:

```
{% block content %}
    <div id="app"></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('homepage') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('homepage') }}
{% endblock %}
```

The corsponding .js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from '../vue/homepage'

new Vue({
    render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

...and the vue file themselfe: (I'd like to use the arrTrans in the div of the "button-overview-lable")

```
<template>
    <div class="button-overview">       
            <div class="button-overview-lable">{{ arrTrans['lb_planning'] }}</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Homepage",
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    @import "../../../core/app/css/helper/variables";
    @import "../css/homepage";
</style>
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Have you tried printing the value to be passed anywhere and something is not working?

Comment: The way I descripted about is not working, it should show what I want to do.

Comment: And what have you tried to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JS variable in twig template and pass json-encoded array. Like this (also we disable automatic html-escaping using `raw` filter):

```
{% block content %}
    <script>
        const arrTrans = JSON.parse('{{ arrTrans|json_encode()|raw }}')
    </script>
    <div id="app"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

But you have to deal with `'` character in your locale strings because it will cause JS syntax error. Replace `raw` filter with `escape('js')`.

So, the final twig template is:

```
{% block content %}
    <script>
        const arrTrans = JSON.parse('{{ arrTrans|json_encode()|escape('js') }}')
    </script>
    <div id="app"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Then in vue app you will just use this variable in `data`:

```
<template>
    <div class="button-overview">
            <div class="button-overview-lable">{{ arrTrans.lb_planning }}</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Homepage',
  data() {
    return {
      arrTrans,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    @import "../../../core/app/css/helper/variables";
    @import "../css/homepage";
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass data from your template file to a javascript file you can use data attribute.

```html
<div id="app" data-trans="{{ arrTrans | json_encode() }}"></div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    trans: null
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.trans = this.$el.getAttribute('data-trans');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, but I had some problems to implement them. What's now working for me was:

- Homepage.html.twig

  ```
  <div ref="translation" data-translation="{{ arrTrans|json_encode()  }}"></div>
  ```
- Homepage.js

  ```
  new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      render: (h) => h(App),
  })
  ```
- homepage.vue

  ```
  <template>
        <div>
          <div>{{ trans }}</div>
          <div>{{ trans['lb_planning'] }}</div>
        </div>
  </template>

  export default {
      name: 'HomePage',
      data() {
          return {
              trans: {}
          };
      },
      mounted() {
          let elTrans = document.querySelector("div[data-translation]");        
          let myTrans = JSON.parse(elTrans.dataset.translation);        
          this.trans= myTrans;
      }
  }
  ```